# Pulling requests from multiple clients with ZMQ

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have a couple of workers waiting to do some jobs. I see that in the PULL/PUSH pattern I need to give the workers the ip address (using the tcp protocol) of the client, so it can listen to requests from there. However, in my case I want to have a lot of clients as well, coming from different IPs with requests... So basically I dont really have a static IP to bind the worker to PULL from. Am I using the wrong pattern or is there a way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using the router-dealer pattern. Your router binds at 2 ends and it has a static IP. It pulls from the multiple clients that connect to it and pushes to the workers on the other end. You can use the ROUTER/DEALER socket types to make this or just use an extra bridge using PUSH/PULL sockets to connect the clients to the workers.

Comment: That 'extra' bridge for PUSH/PULL socket types in zmq is called a `STREAMER`. http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-device#toc5

Comment: Yes, the ``STREAMER`` really solves the problem and I found an excellent working example here: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/streamer.html

Comment: @Tregoreg Is `zmq.STREAMER` of Python the same as `ZMQ_STREAM` socket of the C API?